# Scrapy crawl class skips links and doesn't return response body

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, web-crawler

Right now I am trying to scrape this webpage: http://search.siemens.com/en/?q=iot

For that I need to Extract the Links and parse them which I just learned should be possible with the Crawl class. However my implementation doesn't seem to work. For testing purposes I am trying to return the response body from each website. Unfortunately the spider only opens every third or so link and doesn't give me the response body back.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule


class SiemensCrawlSSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'siemens_crawl_s'
    allowed_domains = ['search.siemens.com/en/?q=iot']
    start_urls = ['http://search.siemens.com/en/?q=iot']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='.//dl[@id="search-resultlist"]/dt/a'), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        yield response.body
```

Comment: Using `scrapy shell`, can you reach those other links that your spider cannot reach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `LOG_LEVEL = 'DEBUG'` on `settings.py` you can see some requests being filtered due to the `allowed_domains` parameter

```
2019-05-10 00:38:27 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.siemens.com': <GET https://www.siemens.com/global/en/home/products/software/mindsphere-iot.html>
2019-05-10 00:38:27 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.industry.siemens.com.cn': <GET https://www.industry.siemens.com.cn/automation/cn/zh/pc-based-automation/industrial-iot/iok2k/Pages/iot.aspx>
2019-05-10 00:38:27 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'w3.siemens.com': <GET https://w3.siemens.com/mcms/pc-based-automation/en/industrial-iot>
2019-05-10 00:38:27 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'new.siemens.com': <GET https://new.siemens.com/global/en/products/services/iot-siemens.html>
```

You can try with `allowed_domains = ['siemens.com', 'siemens.com.cn']`

or dont set `allowed_domains` at all

https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.allowed_domains